# Jquery variable problem

Tags: jquery

The HTML:

```
<div class="first" id="first_id">
<div class="second">text sample</div>
<div class="third"><button type="submit" class="some_class" id="some_id">send</button></div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#some_id").click(function() {
var test = $(this).closest('.first').attr('id');
..
return false;
});
```

I want to replace content of the "first" div using var "test" in jquery code above.
Something like:

```
$("."+test).html('<img src="img/spin.gif">');
```

But when I put this part of the code in function above it does not work. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting the ID but selecting it as a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) (so it should be `$("#"+test)`), but it can be easier, like this:

```
$("#some_id").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.first').html('<img src="img/spin.gif">');
  return false;
});
```

There's no need to go selecting the element again, you already have it, so just calling [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on the element you found with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) works, simpler and faster :)

---

For completeness sake though, what you *should* do is this:

```
$("#some_id").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.first').empty().append('<img src="img/spin.gif">');
  return false;
});
```

Using a [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) call will cleanup the `click` handler we're in, otherwise it'l be left around in `$.cache`...this isn't a big issue, but if you have *lots* of elements it adds up, it's best to always cleanup if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You put id value into the test, but then you use '.' in selector. Instead you should use '#'.